# Position 4 Images Vertically Responisively No Padding

Tags: html, css

I just want to thank everyone for being so helpful, I would of never learnt so much if it wasn't for your guys continual helpfulness.

I'm trying to make a 4 way vertical "collage" of some images without spaces between each picture that is fully responsive when resizing the window and such. The problem I'm having is with space between each photo; I'm trying to figure out how to allow no space between each.

I also encounter a problem when resizing the window to be smaller in which the images flow away from the lion image above and make more white space or padding without sticking to the lion image. It also starts to overlap the lion image when resizing to a bigger size.

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/31/91/d7/3191d75f03ba7d4c570358870c855ed7.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 850px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#collage {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="brand"><a href="#">MINIMAL</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Simplicity is Minimal</h1>

  <div id="home">
    <a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
    <img id="collage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Panthera_tiger_in_a_marshy_area_in_captivity.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
    <img id="collage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Panthera_tiger_in_a_marshy_area_in_captivity.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
    <img id="collage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Panthera_tiger_in_a_marshy_area_in_captivity.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
    <img id="collage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Panthera_tiger_in_a_marshy_area_in_captivity.jpg">
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: you can reset vertical-align to top or bottom to img or reset display to block. that white gap is the same for the text when it stands on the baseline :)

Comment: Add the bootstrap css???? see this fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/mrtjtdz9/

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add below css and I hope it works.-

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.image {
    height: auto;
}
body img {
    display: block;
}`
```

Comment: This eliminates the blank space when resizing but there is still space between the images.

Comment: You add this,but for this you have to use media query  

.image {
    background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/31/91/d7/3191d75f03ba7d4c570358870c855ed7.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: auto;
}